# restore button in inapp purchase

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, in-app-purchase

I uploaded my app with in-app purchase feature to itunes store.But apple rejects my app due to "there is no restore button".If I added "Restore" button,how can I get my locally stored data?Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, when you call `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];`, setting the status of a purchase to YES for something that has been purchased before, there shouldn't be a problem. You won't need to consider the local data you have stored.

To retrieve something from NSUserDefaults:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"intKey];
```

Comment: Ya thank you..But I need to get my local datas.So how to store those datas?

Comment: Where are you storing your local data anyway? NSUserDefaults

Comment: Then you get your stored data in the normal way: Check out my edit

Comment: But after uninstalling and re-installing my app,I can get the previous transaction by "Restore" button.but datas will go right?

Comment: You should write to NSUserDefaults if there was a successful purchase.

Comment: I assume that afer we call restoreCompletedTransactions we need to use something else as well. how can I check what products I bought. I mean for unlock it on my device. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `restoreCompletedTransactions` on the `SKPaymentQueue` to restore your previous transactions

Comment: I assume that afer we call restoreCompletedTransactions we need to use something else as well. how can I check what products I bought. I mean for unlock it on my device. thanks.