# Restore button for inapp purchase restoring all transactions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, in-app-purchase

I uploaded my game to itunes store.But apple rejects it because of there is no restore button.So I added restore button to restore the transactions.My game is having 4 inapp purchases.I bought 2 inapp purchases and uninstalled my game from device.After that I installed the game again and pressed the restore button.But it restores all four transactions.What is the wrong I did? I added the following code in restore button clicked

```
-(void)restore_clicked
{
   [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}
```

Comment: repost of [restore button in inapp purchase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082260/restore-button-in-inapp-purchase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The restore functions restores all transactions from your app that was ever made from your Apple Account. If you previously made the other two purchases at some point when you were testing your app, then they would all be restored, not only the two last ones that were made in your last install.

The reason for this is that if the user decides to buy a new iPhone, or to run your game both on his iPad and his iPhone, he would want to access his in-app purchases in all his devices. A user that logs in with the same Apple account will in this way be able to restore previously bought in-app content.

Btw I think you could do this automatically, without a button? I.e restore previous purchases automatically when the app is started.

Comment: :- Hey followed this post to restore in-app purchases . I encountered with a problem. While restoring if user enters Apple appstore ID when asked by which no in-app has been done , i didnt get any failure message or event in my code . is there something wrong with the implementation ?

Comment: how to get last transaction detail or restore last complete transaction? This above method gives me lots of id and not given last purchase id

Answer (score 2):

Don't restore in-app purchases automatically when the app is started because it will ask them to log in to the iTunes store. That will get really annoying if they need to do it every time.